# accepted process / procedure for writing multithreaded code in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I was asked in a recent interview to name a specific process/procedure that is used in java to implement multi-threading and also to debug multi-threading issues . Although I know a few good practices on how to write good multi-threaded code , I do not know of any specific process that is used for writing multi-threaded/concurrent programs in java.

I did a few searches and read a few blogs as well as books on the subject , but the closest such paradigm I came across was Amdahl's law but that was on the performance aspect of multithreading. Is there any such specific process / algo / set of rules that is used for writing multi-threaded applications in java

Answer (score 0):

The way you've worded the question is pretty ambiguous.  Under "techniques used in java to implement multi-threading," they may have meant synchronization primitives. Java provides monitors with the `synchronize`, `wait` and `notify`.  It implements thread code bodies as `Runnable`s.  Other languages and libraries used different methods.

For implementation, there are multi-thread design patterns supported by the Java libraries.  The producer-consumer pattern is supported by synchronized queues. Also thread pools. There are mutexes and locks for exclusive access by threads to code and data.  Etc.

The JVM is designed to support debugging by providing a built-in API for debuggers.

Of course debugging multi-threaded code is something like an oxymoron.  Bugs are non-deterministic, so merely running without bugs does not mean they're gone.

So the overarching wisdom in writing multi-threaded code is that you must prove it correct in advance, normally by establishing invariants and using provided tools (like synchronization primitives) to enforce them.  Adding assertions to verify the invariants is a way of verifying your proof though seldom a guarantee that it's correct.

Comment: I have reworded my statement. Most of my answers to the questions is what you have explained in the first 3 paragraphs , but the interviewer mentioned explicitly that he was looking for a name that encpasulated those steps

Answer (score 0):

Here's some general ideas for creating safe, multi-threaded Java code:

- **Thread confinement** - Modifying of a mutable datatype should be confined to a single thread to prevent race conditions.
- **Using thread-safe datatypes** - For example, a thread-safe BlockingQueue will safely allow multiple threads to access and modify its contents.
- **Immutable datatypes** - Using datatypes that can't be modified allows them to be safely shared between threads.
- **Synchronization** - Using `synchronize` on methods or objects allows only a single thread to access it